# How do I clean a pot after boiling eggs?

Tags: eggs, cleaning, boiling

After boiling 8 batches of eggs, how can I clean the build up of calcium off the bottom of the pot?

Comment: You could use CLR but make sure you rinse well

Comment: BKF (Bar Keeper's Friend) is fantastic on stainless steel pots.

Answer (score 6):

1. Put some water in the pot
2. Add vinegar or citric acid (whatever you can get your hands on more easily). (Sorry, I have no measurements, I always eyeball it. I guess up to 5% for vinegar is fine, or one or two teaspoons of citric acid depending on the pot-size...)
3. Heat to a rolling boil... (do NOT put your head over the pot to see it it works, especially when using vinegar)
4. After it has boiled for a minute, turn off the heat and let things cool down.
5. Rinse the pot
6. Enjoy the (hopefully) shiny pot :)

Comment: I'd add that if this does not work, you can let a mix of 30/70 vinegar/water sit in the pot for 30 minutes to an hour before scrubbing with warm water and soap.